# how use real function in a test that use an autowired object in?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

In my code i mock an object :

```
 @Mock
ElasticService elasticServiceMock;
@Autowired
ElasticConfiguration elasticConfiguration;
```

an i try to do a test :

```
@Test
public void measureChannelProcessor() throws IOException {
    when(elasticServiceMock.insert(anyString(),anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        String index = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        String message = (String) invocation.getArguments()[1];

        String requestUri = new StringBuilder()
                .append(elasticConfiguration.baseRequestBuilder(index))
                .toString();
}
```

when i call elasticConfiguration.baseRequestBuilder(index) i have null.

the real class of elasticConfiguration is this:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticConfiguration {
@Autowired ElasticParameters elasticParameters;

public String baseRequestBuilder(String index){
    String toRet = new StringBuilder()
            .append(elasticParameters.getProtocol())
            .append("://")
            .append(elasticParameters.getHost())
            .append(":")
            .append(elasticParameters.getPort())
            .append("/")
            .append(index)
            .append("/")
            .append(elasticParameters.getType())
            .append("/")
            .toString();
    return toRet;
}
```

in particular i want simple real class elasticConfiguration but

```
@Autowired
    ElasticConfiguration elasticConfiguration;
```

dont work! and i have java.lang.NullPointerException.

the question is how use an object in Test?

Also if i use @Mock ElasticConfiguration elasticConfiguration;

i have same error but with debug i view that @Autowired ElasticParameters

elasticParameters; in  public class ElasticConfiguration { is null.

Some tips?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: pls show annotations on your test

Answer (score 0):

If you have to `@autowire` the object, then you require some form of **IOC container**, in your case for Java, this is likely Spring.

Typically, for Spring to work in accordance with your tests and to autowire your beans at the correct time, you will need the correct annotations, to tell spring what to do when you execute your test suite.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ElasticConfiguration.class)
```

You should also include whichever configuration class contains the bean definition for `ElasticParameters` in the above statement. So it would look like:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ElasticConfiguration.class, OtherConfiguration.class})
```

Also, if you are using **component-scan** as a means of automatic bean configuration, then simply you can declare an additional annotation:

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.your.package.with.beans")
```

Generally when we use an IOC container to run our tests, they are integration tests or higher in the testing pyramid. Unit tests do not require it.

I would advise you to read more about writing Integration tests [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.2.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html) from the Spring docs. It covers everything you need to know to run your tests correctly.